# soapAction contains colon, not able to access web service

Tags: wsdl

My WSDL has all soap operation defined as like below 
    *<soap:operation soapAction="fun1:fun2:type#getVersion"/>*

I'm not able to create succeed in accessing webservice. I have followed
2 methods none worked

1. Passed method name as *getVersion*, got result as *Cannot find dispatch method*
2. Passed method name as *fun1:fun2:type:getversion*, got result as *Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ':' (code 58) excepted space, or '>' or "/>"
   at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,247]*

Please help on this.

Thanks in Advance
Ashok